# Elegant way to OR/AND member of all elements in array in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a

```
struct A {
   bool field;
};
```

so for an array `A a[32]`, I want to check if all elements in this array have `field` as true. What is a good way to do that? I can think about using `std::accumulate`. Is it the best way in C++11?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of

Comment: @nwp there are two things I hate about those. First, most are not available until C++17. Second, there's no default predicate for simple checking of booleans.

Comment: @MarkRansom Well, you can write your own `all_of` based on `std::all_of` that saves you the need to write that lambda. I probably would not.

Comment: @nwp nor would I, I'd just use the old-fashioned for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) seems to fit closest to your problem.

```
std::all_of(std::begin(a), std::end(a), [](const A &a){return a.field;});
```

---

Besides `#include <algorithm>` for `std::all_of` you may need to `#include <iterator>` for `std::begin` and `std::end`.

Answer (score 5):

An "elegant" C++ way would be to use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

```
std::bitset<32> a;
```

There are [member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/all_any_none) that you can then use to test whether:

- all bits are set to true, `a.all()`
- any bits are set to true, `a.any()`
- none of the bits are set to true, `a.none()`